# Calling a Visual Basic DLL in C++

Tags: c++, dll

I have acquired a DLL that was created in Visual Basic from a third party vendor(**Sensor DLL.dll**).  This DLL contains functions for talking to a sensor, and I need to call these functions from a Visual C++ program I am writing.  The vendor will not provide a header file, and I do not know Visual Basic.  If I had a header file this would be a 15 minute project... instead I am still struggling with it a week later.  Please Help!

I am told one function (**Get_Data**) in the DLL is of the form:

```
Public Function Get_Data(ByVal Handle As String) As String
```

I have tried several methods for calling this Get_Data function with no success:

**Method 1)** the DllImport attribute

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices; 

namespace Sensor
{
```

[DllImport("Sensor DLL.dll", EntryPoint = "Get_Data", CharSet = System::Runtime::InteropServices::CharSet::Unicode)]
    BSTR Get_Data(BSTR Handle);
    }

```
//then I call the function
Sensor::Get_Data(Handle);
```

This method seems to be the closest I have gotten to a sloution.  It compiles, but gives the following error when it runs:

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' occurred**

Additional information: Unable to find an entry point named 'Get_Data' in DLL 'Sensor DLL.dll'.

I have tried various datatype combinations/permutations besides BSTR including BSTR*, wchar_t, int, etc.  It is possible that I missed one, but each datatype returns the same error.

**Method 2)** dllimport storage-class attribute

```
__declspec(dllimport) BSTR Get_Data(BSTR Handle);

//then I call the function
Get_Data(Handle);
```

This method is confusing to me because I don't specify the DLL I want to import from.  I have copied the DLL to the project folder and I have added it to the project manually, so hopefully that means it can be found.  When I compile the linker returns the following errors:

**error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00034F) "wchar_t * __cdecl Get_Data(wchar_t *)" (?Get_Data@@$$FYAPA_WPA_W@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)**

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "wchar_t * __cdecl Get_Data(wchar_t *)" (?Get_Data@@$$FYAPA_WPA_W@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)

I suspected maybe this meant I should be using wchar_t or wchar_t* instead of BSTR, but changing to either datatype results in the same error.

**Method 3)** GetProcAddress

```
typedef BSTR (*Get_Data_Ptr)(BSTR Handle);  
HINSTANCE LoadMe;
LoadMe = LoadLibraryA("Sensor DLL.dll");

if (!LoadMe)
    std::cout << "\nDLL failed to load!\n";

Get_Data_Ptr LibMainGet_Data;  
LibMainGet_Data = (Get_Data_Ptr)GetProcAddress(LoadMe,"Get_Data");

//then I call the function
LibMainGet_Data(Handle);
```

This will compile, but gives the following error when run:

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred**

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

When I mouse over the various parts of this code in debug mode it seems that, like the first method, it was also unable to find the 'Get_Data' entry point in the DLL.

Has anyone called functions from a VB DLL using C++ when you haven't made the DLL yourself and you don't have .idl files, etc?  Does anyone have a working example like this you could share?
Thanks!

Comment: Attributes are not available in C++. Only in managed C++, which is not the same

Comment: Are you intentionally using C++/CLI? Or are you just using it because it's the only way of calling COM objects that you are familiar with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A VB6 DLL is normally a COM server.  You do in fact have the equivalent of a .h file, it has a type library embedded in it.  Start this off with Project + Properties, Common Properties, Framework and References.  Add New Reference button, Browse tab, select the DLL.

Next, View + Object Browser.  You should see the generated Interop library in the list.  Open the node to see what is there.  You write normal managed code, like gcnew, to create the COM object and call the interface methods.  You do need some minimum documentation on the available methods to have a guess at how they should be called.

Comment: You are right, when I do this I can see the list of functions in the DLL in the Object Browser.  It shows Get_Data(System::String).

Comment: I'm still struggling with the last portion of creating the COM object and calling the interface methods.  I have not done that before.

Comment: I don't know what that means.  Ask a real question, get a real answer.  Is this really a "minimum documentation" problem?

Comment: Sorry for being a pain. I'm still reading the COM article suggested by jdehaan but it is well beyond my experience. I see the functions in the Object Browser but I do not know what I need to do to call them in in my program.  I tried simply calling Get_Data(Handle); but it was not recognized.  I also tried to call CoInitialize first, but that did not help. For documentation, all I know is the form mentioned before "Public Function Get_Data(ByVal Handle As String) As String", which will return a string with a value between -16777216 and +16777215. What must I write now to call the function?

Comment: This should be a new question.  I can't fit the answer in a comment box.

Comment: Sure, I'll make one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688325/calling-a-visual-basic-dll-in-c-part-2

Answer (score 1):

I believe the missing piece is the calling convention. C++ has its own function calling convention different than VB6 (I assume VB6 since you haven't stated VB.NET explicitly). VB6 uses STDCALL convention whereas C++, depending on the vendor, uses a different calling convention termed __cdecl, which is why you see the __cdecl in the compiler error line for method #2. It assumes your external function is using that calling convention by default. Calling convention is a set of rules describing how functions call one another; specifically  about how registers are used, what order parameters are delivered in, how by-value / by-reference is determined, etc.

I would suggest sticking with method #3 since method #1 is for Managed C++ which is not standard C++, and method #2 is unfamiliar to me and looks a bit ambiguous. What you want to try is declaring the function pointer typedef to use STDCALL.

```
typedef BSTR (__stdcall *Get_Data_Ptr)(BSTR Handle);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the OLE/COM viewer, in order to view the COM type library in a dll/exe/... you have to open it by using "File->View TypeLib" instead of "File->Bind to File"

Comment: Sorry. This was supposed to go with John's problem with the OLE/COM viewer (see below)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the DLL isn't actually exporting a function named `Get_Data`.  Open up a command prompt and use [dumpbin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c%28VS.71%29.aspx) to get the list of exports of the DLL, e.g.:

```
dumpbin /exports "Sensor DLL.dll"
```

(dumpbin.exe is located in VC\bin within your Visual Studio install folder, which istypically something like `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0`).

Then, replace `Get_Data` with the actual entry point and see if you have any better luck.

Comment: I tried this and dumpbin /exports returned the following: "File Type: DLL, Summary 2000 .reloc 2000.rsrc 2000.sdata C000.txt" - That was all

Answer (score 0):

A Visual basic program normally needs a runtime to execute.

If you have a COM object (implemented in VB) use the COM API to communicate with it from C++. You will have to register the COM first. Here is a thread that explains hot to do that: http://forums.devx.com/archive/index.php/t-87059.html

If you use a .NET language, use the method of Hans Passant with a reference that will create an interop dll for you. This is far much easier.

- Method 1: Do not do that, if you have a COM object that you want to use from a .NET environment, reference it.
- Method 2: You get errors because you lack the the .lib file to properly link to the DLL (statically dynamically linking)
- Method 3: Would be a pure dynamic solution but you have to know the exact names of the methods in the DLL. These may vary according to the parameters and calling convention used. This is very similar (actually identical, I would say) to the issue you face with your Method 1 solution. The name of the method is for yure not "Get_Data" but something else. With a tool like the [dependency viewer](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) you can have a look at the exported names.

Even Method 3 with the right names is likely to fail because if it is a COM object you will need some environment called Appartment to use the COM objects. You "enter" this appartment by calling `CoInitialize`. This creates some magical stuff in the TLS (Thread Local Storage) to perform the COM magic. I hope this explains why your tries will be pointless if the DLL you have is happening to be a COM component, what is quite likely according to the ATL like naming we can see.

EDIT:
I forgot to say that you can also easily see what is inside the dll if it is a COM with the [OLE/COM Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0kh9f4c(v=VS.90).aspx) (normally if you have a compiler you will have such a tool around).

Comment: I am unfamiliar with COM objects but will do some reading. Thanks for the link.  However, I am unable to open the DLL with the OLE/COM Viewer, which gives the error: IMoniker::BindToObject failed on the file moniker created from (....). Bad extension for file. MK_E_INVALIDEXTENSION($800401E6).  Perhaps it is not a COM?