# Preparing a Visual Basic DLL for C++ consumption

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, com

According to [this Microsoft page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx), the #import directive can be used to generate C++ header files from a type library. I have used it sucessfully with 3rd party libraries.

I am now trying to code a User Control in Visual Basic (using XAML) to be consumed in a C++ application. The idea is to have the control raise events that the application loop would then consume.

**1) How can I embed a type library from Visual Basic?** When I use the #import directive with the DLL generated in Visual Basic I get

> error C1083: Cannot open type library file: (dll path here) Error loading type library/DLL. (cpp filename here)

Since the DLL path is correct (and it works when added as reference to another Visual Basic project), I am guessing the DLL is missing some sort of export information.

**2) How can a User Control find the `HWND` of its parent?**
I would like to use it later to [post a message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944.aspx).

---

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3679967/2549876) that asks something similar. In my case, I will create the DLL.

Comment: You'll have to apply the [ComVisible(true)] attribute on public interfaces and classes to make them usable with #import.  Then generate the type library with Tlbexp.exe or Regasm.exe /tlb.

Comment: @HansPassant, thank you! You send me in the right direction. In VB, it was <ComVisible(true)>.